# Lync ActiveX inside SharePoint will not display the user image, unless we moved the mouse over the username

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, active-directory, user-profile-service

I am implementing a SharePoint 2013 community site. And inside the members sections I can view the member picture inside a pop-up when I move the mouse over the username, as shown in the picture.

[image]

But inside the members section the member’s picture will always display a shadow image (grey and white). So is there a way to force the Lync ActiveX to display the members pictures, inside the members section, even if we do not move the mouse over it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have MySite Web application and MySite Host site collection created in the web application? If your answer is affirmative can you go to your mysite to check if you have profile picture?

If you are still not having the profile picture you have to map the picture that is in your active directory in the User Profile and perform a sync of pictures

Answer (score 1):

No, since it is not really connected in both directions to SharePoint, the active x control extracts some info from SharePoint to identify which user you have hovered, no more.

What you should do is configure the User Profile Service to extract this information from AD. Basics outlined here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/lukeb/archive/2013/01/04/sharepoint-import-a-picture-from-ad-for-the-user-profile.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The control in SharePoint 2013 is in 2 parts. ON the page, it is looking at the profile image. The hovercard is using Lync Exchange and AD. It sounds like the Lync part is working and the SharePoint part is not.

Do users have profile images associated with their user profiles?

Comment: no they have images inside lync server, but no images inside sharepoint.

Comment: Then the images will not show on the page, they will only show on hover. The page loads the image from the SharePoint User Profile PictureURL property and those pictures are usually (though not always) stored in SharePoint. You could try importing the image from AD.